# How to display PST time irrespective of the location of the user?

Tags: javascript

I need to write a javascript function that returns current PST date time even if the page is opened in another timezone. I am not the brightest javascript head... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript alone will not be able to do this. Javascript is client side and would only pick up the users local time. EDIT: It seems javascript can achieve this, using `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` but I would *personally* opt for the second option.

You could always set up an AJAX function that requests the time from the server (e.g. http://mydomain.com/ajax/currenttime) and then display this to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Universal time and just translate it to your PST time using the javascript method `Date.UTC(year, month, day [, hours, minutes, seconds, ms])`

**Edit:**
Taken directly from [http://www.ecma-international.org](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)

> **15.9.1.9** Local TimeConversion from UTC to local time is defined by

```
LocalTime(t) = t + LocalTZA + DaylightSavingTA(t)
```

> Conversion from local time to UTC is
>   defined by

```
UTC(t) = t – LocalTZA – DaylightSavingTA(t – LocalTZA)
```

*Note that UTC(LocalTime(t)) is not necessarily always equal to t*

Comment: I believe this only works if the user's machine time and timezone is correctly set. A server-side solution would work more accurately.